# Keep one column at upper right of grid for all breakpoints

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I've been using the grid system in Twitter Bootstrap on several projects - but can't seem to crack this nut.

I want to place a blue promotion cell in the upper right corner of the grid like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Sample code**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 big">Promotion</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">6</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">7</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">8</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">9</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">10</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">11</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">12</div>                   
</div>
```

Playground: http://jsfiddle.net/3fr3rsL3/

Any help is appreciate

Comment: You'll have to move it around in the DOM. In the first image, the promotion cell is the 6th one. In the second, it's the 4th. And then it's the 3rd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me the simplest answer would be to place it third in order in the row.  This will keep it ordered correctly on the narrowest viewports. Next, use .col-xs-12 just on the .promotion `<div>` to achieve the full width on narrow viewports. Finally, use .pull-right to correct the ordering on wider viewports.  Your original code is almost there, and with the example you've given I don't see a need to complicate it much.

Check this fork of your fiddle for what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/rrt22y5p/

Comment: Also a really elegant and shorter solution to my problem - Thanks!

Comment: Very nice, and much simpler than my approach. Was this technique documented somewhere, or was it an accidental discovery?

Comment: It's just lucky that the constraints of the problem line up well with the Bootstrap grid and its behaviors. I find push and pull cumbersome to manage and document in more complex grids, but they are definitely necessary sometimes.  In this case, it doesn't appear that they are.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is using Bootstrap's `push` and `pull` [ordering classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3fr3rsL3/5/)**

...

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-md-push-3 col-lg-2 col-lg-push-6 big">
    <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-md-pull-3 col-lg-2 col-lg-pull-2">
    <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-lg-pull-2">
    <div>5</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-lg-pull-2">
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

...

Forcing float on the column at all sizes resolves the issue of overlap for mobile:

```
.big {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million for your work - really helpfull and well documented